# what is a term for "not caring for something that isn't beneficial to you"?

Tags: phrase-requests

I am currently writing a paper on the hunger games and I have a thesis stating there is a lot of "Indifference towards other who aren't beneficial" in the novel

I would like to narrow down this thesis or find a term fitting its description

Comment: Keeping your eye on the ball?

Comment: While I believe I understand your intent,  it could be that different people will read it in other ways.  Questions here are not about "creative writing" and try to avoid "best word for this" contests.   If you could make clear that it was ONLY  the meaning "indifference to to others that are not beneficial" and excluded "what would you call a a person like that"  it might help the question.  Also :  making it clear if you wanted to ONLY discuss the indifference but spend little time on the favoritism on the flip side of the coin that might also help.

Answer (score 0):

[**Fair weather friend**](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/fair-weather_friend): one who is helpful or friendly only when it is to their advantage.

I would say, however, that this idiom has implications only for one friend. The idea is that a fair weather friend will abandon you should you cease to be beneficial to them. My own opinion of The Hunger Games is that there are a few mutually beneficial friendships where both parties benefit for a while (e.g. game participants joining forces at the start of the game), but the eventual back stabbing is unavoidable and somewhat expected.

Comment: I'm am thinking that the OP might be writing an advanced enough paper that they are not trying to explain all the dynamics between the participants or even the plot line of the novel itself but instead looking at the social science  dynamics of how american literature can reinforce "ablism" and "elitism"  bias(or maybe that was only what my advanced writing classes were like) Like you imply though, it would be hard to fault someone put in a zero-sum life or death survival situation.

Answer (score 0):

Your question asks for a word by expressing a "double negative" description. This is, in a sense, like asking for a word or phrase for "**caring** for something that **is** beneficial to you". A good word for that would be "utilitarian".  That is "to care about what is useful, and to not care about what is not useful (superfluous)". "Utilitarian" would be a good term that is consistent with the "Indifference towards others who aren't beneficial (are superfluous)" in the novel.

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/utilitarian

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/superfluous?s=t

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer ~ A good expert answer includes explanation, context, and supporting facts. This is what makes the answer useful – not only to the person asking, but to future visitors to the page. Please consider expanding your answer. Expert partial answers are welcome, but notions, trial balloons, offhand ideas, guesses, anecdotes, and general discussion are not answers. If you are unsure what the asker is looking for, a better way is to request clarification in a comment on the question.

Comment: @user22542   While I initially thought the question had "double negative" issues as you allude, there IS something different between "looking for what is useful" and  "this way that you treat what is not useful" .  The complexity here is what makes it a good question, IMO , not a 'best answer' game.

Comment: By opting for "utilitarian" the converse suggested is something akin to "wasteful" or "frivolous" or "luxurious".  This approach does not work  if the intent is to focus on the depictions and interactions and dialogue of those 'less useful' in the books.

Comment: The word "utilitarian" surely does "address the favoritism" aspect as well, I think.  The exploration of the term is possible within the context of a paper.  When I just read the question as asked, the immediate answer, as a term, becomes "indifference".  That is the same term used in the thesis of the asker.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should probably coin your own term in your exposition and then use your coined term as a reference.

Why?  If you were to choose an already existing idiom, you would risk bringing aspects of that idiom that imply different things than you might hope to define.

I would recommend the word **Expedience** as part of a coined term.

... and **then couple it with another word** that best fits the tone you would like to take ... it might be  "**expedient chauvinism**" (which might carry too much 'hate bias' though) or **bias of expedience** or similar.

You might start with a longer description of the situation working the word in,  "they all show an indifference to those that are less useful to them: a bias based on expedience or which I will refer to as "**expedient-neglect**"  (or **expedient-indifference**).
( or something similar that you like the sound of better)

.. using a hyphen for a coined term might help remind the reader that it is your own term.

> [**expedience** at Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/expedience)
>
> 2.
> a regard for what is politic or advantageous rather than for what is right or just; a sense of self-interest.

The reason why "expedience" does not stand on it's own is that "regard for what is advantageous rather than right and just" does not in itself imply it is directed at people.  "indifference" would not either and , 'bias' not only for people, and "chauvanism" and "bigotry" have become tied to gender and racial bias.  "Expedient Elitism" would imply a bit of arrogance even if not intended. All words have some rhetorical baggage to them .

While **expedient indifference** would not directly refer to people, given your exposition I believe a reader will remember that you have set up the term to refer to other participants.   I would try **expedient-indifference** going in knowing that someone reading it without context might not guess your full intent.